# What's with the weird HoldRest Attribute of ParallelMap?

Tags: bugs, hold, attributes, parallelization

**Bug introduced in 10.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.1. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier**

---

I have noticed some odd behavior of `ParallelMap`: When the list, that is mapped over, is not inserted explicitly (but rather in the form of some other command, like `Range[...]`), there are some cases, where I get unexpected results. For example, when I run

```
ParallelMap[f,Range[Range[4]]]
```

I get

> `{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4]}`

instead of the expected

> `{f[{1}], f[{1, 2}], f[{1, 2, 3}], f[{1, 2, 3, 4}]}`

which is what I get, when I run

```
ParallelMap[f,Evaluate[Range[Range[4]]]]
```

If I do the same thing with `Map` instead of `ParallelMap`, I do get the expected result. Now, I realize, that this is ultimately because `ParallelMap` has the attribute `HoldRest`, but this is in stark contrast to the Documentation stating

> `ParallelMap` will give the same results as `Map`, except for side effects during the computation.

Is this a bug, or some intended behavior I just don't understand (and the Documentation fails to convey)? If this is a Bug, then why would `ParallelMap` have the attribute `HoldRest` in the first place? Neither the `levelspec` parameter, not the `Method` or `DistributedContexts` options seem to justify this. Also, some lists *are* evaluated before they are mapped over (e.g. `ParallelMap[f,Range[4]]` gives the same result as `Map` and as `ParallelMap[f,Evaluate[Range[4]]]`). Any ideas?

Comment: I would report this to Wolfram support.  Can you do that please?

Comment: I looked a little bit at the sources of `ParallelMap` (found in `Combine.m`).  It reduces to `ParallelCombine`, which treats certain seconds arguments such as `Range`, `Table`, `FileNames`, etc. in a special way. Why? I didn't take the time to figure it out, but I assume it may be an attempt at optimization.  This is where things go wrong.  If we define `range=Range`, and use `range` (to prevent `ParallelCombine` from using the special-case implementation), then the problem goes away.

Comment: I am going ahead and tagging this as a bug, but *please do report it to Wolfram*.

Comment: I just reported it to Wolfram.

Comment: I see this bug in Mathematica 8.0.4 as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs I assume this is indeed a form of optimization. If you evaluate the `Range` before parallellizing, you have to transport a bunch of numbers (probably a lot of them) to the subkernels, which is usually slower than just constructing the correct numbers on the subkernels.

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed in version `13.2.0`

[image: fix]